# GMX's "Text Pattern Profiler" blocks transactional emails in English

Tags: email, spam, email-spam, transactional-email

My web application is sending transactional emails to its users (like "You received a payment", "Please activate your account", "Your article has been sold"). GMX users report regularly that those emails are marked as SPAM because of the "Text Pattern Profiler". I can reproduce the problem with my own account, but only emails in English are affected, German emails from my web application are delivered without problems.

So I am pretty sure that the content must be the problem (as "Text Pattern Profiler" already sais :) ), but I don't know how to solve it. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I contacted GMX support about this after reading this question.  I asked for either of the following two things:

1. A link to some tips / tricks for senders that I could recommend
2. A tool to help test emails against their Text Pattern Profiler

They responded saying they couldn't help because that information was proprietary.  If I were you, I would recommend to your users that they migrate away from GMX.

**GMX Response:**

> Dear GMX Customer,
>
> Our sincere apologies for our delayed reply. We thank you for your
>   enquiry and will hopefully answer it to your satisfaction.
>
> Unfortunately we cannot do that. Not only is the spam filter
>   proprietary in nature to a third party, furthermore we are not allowed
>   to disclose any information regarding this. We apologise.
>
> Should you have any further questions or remarks, please do not
>   hesitate to contact us again.
>
> With kind regards,
>
> Your GMX Support Team.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. Indeed it seems that our mails only have problems with GMX, GMail and other providers don't mark our mails as Spam. So I'll recommend our users to check their spam folders regularly...

Comment: Thank you very much for investigation!